# Google Recaptcha Serverside validation V3 Not getting response

Tags: php, api, recaptcha-v3

Error Message We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information. I created this reCaptcha code, it works well but I don not know how can I validate it, I thought it was validating with the function grecaptcha.getResponse(); but it was not so. Then I check the server side validation API call on POSTMAN but it is not getting Success message . Any one know the solution please help. If i miss any parameter to pass through the API call.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
'secret'   => 6LcIwEwjAAAAAM7KEVDbW4Q6DCWBz_ErUc1l5sYPssggfdfdfdfdf,
 'response' => 'user response token',]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = @json_decode($data);
if ($response && $response->success)
{ // validation succeeded, user input is correct
}
```

Please help and [Please check the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxomc.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjEay.png)

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far in your question, then someone can copy/paste it and test it out.

Comment: Serverside validation im not added in my code , I just checked the response in POSTMAN . But in there it showing false response

Comment: Code is attached User reponse token is not given

Comment: It looks like you are sending a POST request in postman - but with the parameters actually appended to the URL, instead of having them as _real_ POST parameters ...?

Comment: Yes. Already added the parameter in Parameter section in POSTMAN

Comment: Don't you need the secret in quotes as well in your `curl_setopt()` call?

Comment: No , secret is not correct one, it is a dummy value